# Markdown in jupyter-notebook producing only one ouput overwriting the prev. one

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, markdown

I am using jupyter notebook, trying to have a markdown output. This is the minimal example of what I am trying to do (in the original code, the various strings to be print are coming from different functions):

```
from IPython.display import Markdown as md
md("hello")
md("world")
```

the output is

```
world
```

instead of the expected

```
hello
world
```

I really would like to avoid resorting to something like merging the strings as in:

```
md("hello\nworld")
```

or passing the different outputs to a file and then read it

Is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `display`

```
from IPython.display import Markdown as md
display(md("hello"))
display(md("world"))
```

Answer (score 1):

The newline character \n is not interpreted correctly in the Markdown formatting, use the tag "br" instead.

```
from IPython.display import Markdown as md
md("hello" + "<br>" + "world")
```